# Is there a convenience store/grocery at the Bora Bora airport?

Tags: airports, tahiti

Is there a store at the Bora Bora airport in Tahiti? Can I buy toiletries, groceries, and/or alcohol there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tahiti airport authority lists three [shops available at Bora Bora airport.](http://tahiti-aeroport.pf/articles.php?id=63)  Below is my translation, though there are a few phrases that I'm not sure I've translated correctly.

> **Bars & restaurants:**
>
> Snack Pora Pora
>
> **Shops:**
>
> Arana: Tel 67 68 67 ou 67 52 38
>
> - Newsstand with French & foreign magazines, book sales, postcards, video cassettes, tobacco, snacks, clothing
> - Open Monday 06h10 to 17h10 - Tuesday 09h50 to 17h10 - Wednesday 09h10 to 18h50 - Thursday 07h05 to 19h05 - Friday 08h15 to 18h35 - Saturday 06h50 to 18h25 - Sunday 08h40 to 19h55
>
> Kaimana : Tel 67 51 99
>
> - Newsstand, books, postcards & stamps, curios, clothing, candy, tobacco, visual products (photo film, audio & video), essentials (?) (*première necessité*)
> - Open from 05h30 until the last flight Monday through Friday.

The terminal itself is quite small;  you can see the plan below (also available [here](http://tahiti-aeroport.pf/carteBora.html).)

[image]